# Can't boot from external APFS formatted SSD

Tags: macos, startup, external-disk, high-sierra, apfs

I have a Mac mini with macOS High Sierra and an external SSD drive connected via USB also with High Sierra on it.

**After converting the external SSD to APFS it doesn't boot** anymore - my Mac can't see it as bootable and doesn't show it when booting with holding Option key.

If I go to System Preferences -> Startup Disk and choose the external drive I get an error:

```
You can’t change the startup disk to the selected disk.

Running bless to place boot files failed.
```

It seems that macOS can't install some boot files on that disk. Running First Aid on that disk in Disk Utility also produces an error:

```
Verifying allocated space.
error: Underallocation Detected on Main device: (7219537+1) bitmap address (184373)
Space Verification failed.
The volume /dev/disk1s2 could not be verified completely.
```

What can I do to restore those boot files and make the SSD finally work? I don't want to erase it and reinstall.

Comment: Was it possible to boot from the external disk _before_ installing macOS 10.13?

Comment: @oa- Yes, when it was formatted as HFS+ it was possible to boot from it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question... (happens a lot to me lately)

I did manage to get it to boot from the broken SSD by first booting from a USB drive I prepared earlier with High Sierra install files on it and then installing to the SSD drive on top of the old system.

There was a weird thing happening during first reboot after the installation where my screen would flash and turn off. In fact I think I didn't really finish the installation, I think the installer didn't even copy all the files, but everything seems to work fine now so I'm pretty happy (and my old files and apps are in place).